# What does '% complete' signify in gitlab releases?

Tags: gitlab

I created a Release on Gitlab (available, on the left side panel Deployments>Releases) It was just for kicks but I'm left wondering what is meant, when I click on my newly created Release, by 89% Complete above a status bar showing the same. I cancelled the spawned pipeline, right at the beginning.

I can see no clues on the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/releases/), of which I'd welcome more, though an explanation of said metric will suffice.

[Edit]
I just created another release; same behaviour. 89% complete

[further edit, added screenshot on request]
[image]

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of what you're seeing?
I'd like to update the documentation but want to be sure I have it correct.
If you're interested in submitting the merge request, there's an "edit this page" link at the bottom that takes you to the source

Comment: I will include a screenshot, but in hindsight, it's fairly intuitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to refer to a number of relating 'issues', which have been closed:

```
Issues 9
Open: 1
•
Closed: 8
```